# How do you get URL from UIImage in Swift or Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UIImage object like this (in Swift):

```
image : UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
self.imageView.image = image
// Want to do:
// seeImagePath : String = imagePath
```

How do I get back the imagePath of this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image (UIImage) has no "path". It is an image, not a file. It is nothing but a bitmap of colors being held in memory.

You had the path before, when you had a variable called `imagePath`; if you want to retain that info, retaining it is up to you. It has nothing whatever to do with the UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` holds the data retrieved from the contents of that file. Once it has loaded the file, it won't know the path of the file. You will need to cache your `imagePath` variable and refer to that.